# the collatz func in automate boring stuff with python

Tags: python

I tried writing a code for the `collatz` func .But somehow i failed in it.i am just sharing the code which i tried.can you figure out the mistake

```
def my_input():
    a=input("enter:")
    collatz(a)

def myprint(y):
    print(y)
    if (y!=1):
        my_input()

def collatz(number):
    if (number%2)==0:
        return myprint(number/2)
    else:

        return myprint(3*number+1)
my_input()
```

Comment: your mistake is most probably `int(input("enter:"))`

Comment: Are you getting an error? If you are, it is important to read the error message and include it in your post.

Comment: @Axois but how do i do that ..do i need to delete my question to close it

Comment: @nehasamala You don't need to do anything. Having a question closed as duplicate is not a bad thing. If the answer you got below helped you, you can accept it by clicking on the chek mark below the votes button, but there is no obligation to accept an answer. (And contrary to what some users write: Accepting an answer does not close a question.)

Comment: @nehasamala If you still want to delete your question you can click the "delete" link beneath it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your mistake is `int(input("enter:"))`, because you are passing in a string into your function `collatz(number)`, without converting it into `int`.

Welcome to stackoverflow, next time please include things like your expected outputs or what error you are receiving so that people can easily help you. You can read about how to ask a question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)